# Problema al modificar datos - Update PHP + AJAX +JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenos días gente, nuevamente con un problema.
Tengo un sistema de noticias implementado.
Al listar las noticias y clickear en el boton **editarNoticia**. Aparece la noticia con todos los campos para editar junto con un input "file" que si se edita una noticia, junto con su imagen, reemplaza a la anterior imagen.

El problema yo creo que está en el AJAX, no se que estoy haciendo mal o como llamar al ID de la noticia correspondiente. Yo ya hice el BORRAR y me funciona correctamente pero no se porque no me sale con el editar que es casi parecido.

**Con esto traigo las noticias. (Esto funciona correctamente).** No pongo el codigo anterior, pq no es necesario supongo.

```
elseif ($accion == 'editarNoticias'){

$id = $_POST['id'];

//Consulta BD Editar Noticia segun el ID.
$statement2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE idNoticia = $id");
$statement2->execute();
$noticias = $statement2->fetchAll();

//MODIFICAR DESDE ACA
echo "<h1 class='text-center m-5'>Editar noticias SB</h1>
<form id='formEditarNoticia' class='text-center' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
echo "<div class='form-group mt-5'>
<input type='text' id='". $noticia['idNoticia'] ."' value='" . $noticia['idNoticia'] . "' name='idNoticia' >
<input type='text' name='imagenNoticia-guardada' value='" . $noticia['imagenNoticia'] . "'>
<input type='file' class='form-control-file mx-auto' name='imagenNoticia' id=' placeholder=' aria-describedby='fileHelpId'>
<small id='fileHelpId' class='form-text text-muted text-center'>Seleccione la imagen que quiere subir...</small></div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
    <input name='tituloNoticia' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['tituloNoticia'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
<input name='noticiaCorta' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['noticiaCorta'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mb-3'>
    <textarea name='noticiaCompleta' rows='20' cols='50' type='text' class='form-control'>" 
    . $noticia['noticiaCompleta'] . "</textarea>
</div>

<div class='d-inline-block'>
    <button class='enviarEditarNoticia btn btn-success'>EDITAR NOTICIA</button>
    <a href='index.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>VOLVER</button></a>
</div>
</form>";
}

  }
```

Una vez que visualizo la noticia, la edito y le doy al botón EDITAR NOTICIA (que su clase es **enviarEditarNoticia**) y su AJAX el siguiente (**A MI PARECER EL PROBLEMA ES AQUÍ... No se como enviarle el ID de la noticia ya que en DATA estoy usando el formData."**:

```
        $("#seccionEditarNoticia").on("click", ".enviarEditarNoticia", function() 
     {
        $('#formEditarNoticia').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subirNoticia.php?p=modificar",
            data: new FormData($('#formEditarNoticia')[2]),
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(datos) {
                $('#mensaje').empty();
                $('#mensaje').append(datos);
            }
        });
    });
```

Y bueno al clickear ahí, me debería llevar aquí...

```
}elseif ($accion == 'modificar') {

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}

    $idNoticia = $_POST['idNoticia'];
    $imagenNoticia_guardada = $_POST['imagenNoticia-guardada'];
    $imagenNoticia = $_FILES['imagenNoticia'];
    $tituloNoticia = $_POST['tituloNoticia'];
    $noticiaCorta = $_POST['noticiaCorta'];
    $noticiaCompleta = $_POST['noticiaCompleta'];

    if (empty($imagenNoticia['name'])) {
        $imagenNoticia = $imagenNoticia_guardada;
    } else {
        $carpeta_destino = '../img/noticias/';
        $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino . $_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
        $imagenNoticia = $_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name'];
    }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
        "UPDATE noticias SET tituloNoticia = :tituloNoticia, noticiaCorta = :noticiaCorta, noticiaCompleta = :noticiaCompleta, imagenNoticia = :imagenNoticia WHERE idNoticia = $idNoticia"
    );

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':tituloNoticia' => $tituloNoticia,
        ':noticiaCorta' => $noticiaCorta,
        ':noticiaCompleta' => $noticiaCompleta,
        ':imagenNoticia' => $imagenNoticia
    ));

        echo "La noticia ha sido editada correctamente.";

     }
```

No puse el codigo completo del IF con el agregar o borrar porque eso funciona correctamente.

Espero que me puedan dar una mano para poder modificar esto.
Si falta algo de información, o es necesario los codigos completos, los edito.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el inicio del formulario fuera del bucle foreach, por lo tanto se cierra tras la primera noticia y a partir de entonces cada navegador hará lo que le venga en gana.

Debes ubicarlo dentro del bucle, para que tengas tantos formularios como noticias y sea mas simple el envío de actualización.
Además concatenamos el id de la noticia al id del formulario para que sea único.

```
elseif ($accion == 'editarNoticias'){

$id = $_POST['id'];

//Consulta BD Editar Noticia segun el ID.
$statement2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE idNoticia = $id");
$statement2->execute();
$noticias = $statement2->fetchAll();

//MODIFICAR DESDE ACA
echo "<h1 class='text-center m-5'>Editar noticias SB</h1>";

foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
echo "
<form id='formEditarNoticia_" . $noticia['idNoticia'] . "' class='text-center' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class='form-group mt-5'>
<input type='text' id='". $noticia['idNoticia'] ."' value='" . $noticia['idNoticia'] . "' name='idNoticia' >
<input type='text' name='imagenNoticia-guardada' value='" . $noticia['imagenNoticia'] . "'>
<input type='file' class='form-control-file mx-auto' name='imagenNoticia' id=' placeholder=' aria-describedby='fileHelpId'>
<small id='fileHelpId' class='form-text text-muted text-center'>Seleccione la imagen que quiere subir...</small></div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
    <input name='tituloNoticia' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['tituloNoticia'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
<input name='noticiaCorta' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['noticiaCorta'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mb-3'>
    <textarea name='noticiaCompleta' rows='20' cols='50' type='text' class='form-control'>" 
    . $noticia['noticiaCompleta'] . "</textarea>
</div>

<div class='d-inline-block'>
    <button class='enviarEditarNoticia btn btn-success'>EDITAR NOTICIA</button>
    <a href='index.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>VOLVER</button></a>
</div>
</form>";
}

  }
```

Después, en el ajax, envíamos los datos con:

```
   $(".enviarEditarNoticia").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subirNoticia.php?p=modificar",
        data: $(event.target.form).serialize(),
        contentType: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(datos) {
            $('#mensaje').empty();
            $('#mensaje').append(datos);
        }
    });
});
```

Salvo errores de sintaxis creo que la solución es más o menos acertada.

En el script del ajax es posible que sobre la parte de:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}
```

pues no hay ningún elemento con `name = "id"` ni se añade mediante javascript.